# Libgdx fatal exception on android

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a problem that when i start my application it starts normal up but whenever i click a button that redirects the user to another screen it gives me  a fatal exception error and then there pops up that the application stops working. I haven't had this problem before.

here is the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 30310
Process: com.mygdx.game, PID: 13802
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/swing/JFrame;
    at com.mygdx.Launch.SpriteBatchLaunch.create(SpriteBatchLaunch.java:18)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:311)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1555)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1270)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.swing.JFrame" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.mygdx.Launch.SpriteBatchLaunch.create(SpriteBatchLaunch.java:18) 
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:311) 
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1555) 
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1270) 
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:678)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:711)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:944)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2303)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5943)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/com.mygdx.game-vpxjcfg_OIcYQ3fuJxTb7g==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
 at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:678)
```

Comment: Android does not have Swing classes. You cannot use them.

Comment: That's the correct answer, why did you just comment?

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/swing/JFrame;

Your code creates an instance of `JFrame` which is a part of Swing and is not available on Android. You should use libGDX-specific GUI instead - Scene2D.

See the [Scene2D UI documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui).